# android How do I get value of some columns by inserting half a word database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How do I get value of some columns by inserting half a word

[image]

how am i do it without loop on all the minutes of some days

I tried to do it `select Price from Records where item  = '05.02'` but it wanted an exact sentence

Comment: For your (future) sanity use ISO date format: https://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT price FROM Records WHERE date LIKE '%05.02%'
```